# Instrument Java 17 with AspectJ

Tags: aspectj, java-17, jep-396

When I try to run an AspectJ instrumentation with Java 17, I always get errors like the following:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.initializeForJava11(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:1069)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.defineClass(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:1096)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.access$300(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:66)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor$SimpleGeneratedClassHandler.acceptClass(ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor$WeavingClassFileProvider$1.acceptResult(WeavingAdaptor.java:917)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1431)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1192)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:549)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:385)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:115)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:780)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:675)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @6acbcfc0
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MethodHandles.java:259)
        ... 31 more
```

You can reproduce this by running the example from https://github.com/DaGeRe/aspect-final-example (`runMainWithoutError.sh`, since the MWE was originally to demonstrate a Java 11 problem). If you run this with Java 11, everything runs fine, if you run this with Java 17 you get the above error.

Is there a known workaround for this, or any way to use AspectJ with Java 17?

**EDIT** The exact failing versions where:

```
reichelt@reichelt-desktop:~/nvme/workspaces/dissworkspace/aspect-final-example/woven-project$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
reichelt@reichelt-desktop:~/nvme/workspaces/dissworkspace/aspect-final-example/woven-project$ javac -version
javac 17.0.1
```

The same happens with GraalVM CE:

```
reichelt@reichelt-desktop:~/nvme/workspaces/dissworkspace/aspect-final-example/woven-project$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 21.3.0 (build 17.0.1+12-jvmci-21.3-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 21.3.0 (build 17.0.1+12-jvmci-21.3-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Due to the error message, I would assume that this somehow is caused by AspectJ not (correctly?) using the modules.

Comment: can you mention jdk/jre version if possible

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added the exact version

Comment: It’s funny that this problem occurs in a method having the name `initializeForJava11`. I looked up the code and it’s like stone age people discovering a modern axe and using it only for creating a new club. They use the `java.lang.invoke` package including Java 9+ features, just to try to hack into `ClassLoader.defineClass` again. Instead of using the [`defineClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass(byte%5B%5D)) of the very API they’re just using for the hack attempt, to do the desired operation without hacks.

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt, would you mind verifying, then possibly accepting and upvoting my answer? I do think it is correct. I even answered a second question you did not even ask, because I noticed the other problem in your MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, your addition works and thereby AspectJ can be used with Java 17 :) 
To the second question: We already discussed this in another Stackoverflow question and this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563709 (and I just reused the MCVE for the Java 17 problem demonstration). Unfortunately, there is nothing new regarding this problem. The original code is already refactored in `@Before`/`@After` advices, nevertheless a fix would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Running AspectJ LTW on JDK 16+

As described in the [AspectJ 1.9.7 release notes](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/README-197.html), due to JEP 396 you need to add `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to your Java command line.

#### `IllegalAccessError` in your aspect

The problem you have when running your `runMainWithError.sh` script is documented in [AspectJ issue #563710](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563710). There is an advice which ought to be inlined, but is not.

Looking at your around advice, I see that it proceeds, but it does not actually change any parameters or return values. So you can simply split it into a before/after-advice pair. Actually, you are not even doing anything after proceeding, so even a simple before-advice would suffice:

```java
@Before("notWithinAspect() && noSet()")
public void afterStuff(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
  System.out.println("=== Call: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature() + " " + thisJoinPoint.getKind());
  System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation() + " " + thisJoinPoint.getStaticPart());
  System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.toLongString());
}
```

If for whatever reason you do need an around advice, you better explicitly only weave the joinpoint types you need instead of excluding `set(private * *)`. The latter does not work because it seems to be evaluated dynamically rather than statically, i.e. joinpoint matching happens during runtime where you expect it to happen during weaving time. I have not fully analysed that, but the suggested workarounds should fix your aspect.

---

Incidentally, I was surprised to see your approach to shade the aspect library into the AspectJ weaver instead of simply putting it on the classpath and using the weaver as a Java agent separately. That seems over-engineered and somewhat contrived, forcing you to generate a new manifest in order to emulate the weaver's original one. It also makes the build slower and the weaving process no quicker. Is there any specific reason you did this?

---

**Update:** I analysed the situation a bit, simply configuring the load-time weaver to dump the woven class files:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.aspectj.org/dtd/aspectj_1_5_0.dtd">
<aspectj>
  <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="de.test..*"/>
    <dump within="de.test..*"/>
  </weaver>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="de.aspectjtest.ExampleAspect"/>
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

When decompiling `FinalFieldConstructorExample`, I see this:

```java
class FinalFieldConstructorExample {
  private final Integer parameters;

  FinalFieldConstructorExample() {
    JoinPoint var5 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, ajc$this, ajc$this);
    ExampleAspect var10000 = ExampleAspect.aspectOf();
    Object[] var6 = new Object[]{ajc$this, var5};
    var10000.aroundStuff((new AjcClosure3(var6)).linkClosureAndJoinPoint(69648), ajc$tjp_0);
  }

  // (...)
}
```

So you see that the around-advice is executed in `ExampleAspect`, and from there it is simply forbidden to initialise a final field in `FinalFieldConstructorExample`. You also see that other than it looks like in the source code, the final field's initialisation is not somehow done "before" or "outside of" the constructor, but actually inside the constructor. This becomes more evident if we decompile the version with the before-advice where there is no more call to an external around-advice:

```java
class FinalFieldConstructorExample {
  private final Integer parameters;

  FinalFieldConstructorExample() {
    JoinPoint var8 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_7, (Object)null, (Object)null);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var8);
    super();
    JoinPoint var7 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_6, this, this);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var7);
    JoinPoint var6 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_2, this, this);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var6);
    byte var2 = 5;
    JoinPoint var1 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, this, (Object)null, Conversions.intObject(var2));
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var1);
    // Convert int to Integer
    Integer var4 = Integer.valueOf(var2);
    JoinPoint var3 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_1, this, this, var4);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var3);
    // Write Integer to final field
    this.parameters = var4;
  }

  // (...)
}
```

We can simplify the situation more by changing the field type from `Integer` to `int` (`private final int parameters = 5;`) in order to avoid the conversion step:

```java
class FinalFieldConstructorExample {
  private final int parameters;

  FinalFieldConstructorExample() {
    JoinPoint var3 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_5, (Object)null, (Object)null);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var3);
    super();
    JoinPoint var2 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_4, this, this);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var2);
    JoinPoint var1 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, this, this);
    ExampleAspect.aspectOf().beforeStuff(var1);
    this.parameters = 5;
  }

  // (...)
}
```

Comment: **Update:** I added the result of analysing the byte code created by the AspectJ weaver.